# I don't have a large cutting board, but I do have a large table with a wood top

Tags: bread, cutting-boards

So I want to start making bread, specifically, brioche.

But I don't have a large wooden cutting board. I do, however, have a table with a wooden top.

Are there any consequences(negative ones of course) to using your table as board for making bread?

Comment: Why do you need a cutting board to make bread? - I make mine on a stainless steel surface... How nice of a table is it? Is it "butcher block" or is some sort of dining table?

Comment: What is your tabletop finished with? It's not something that could come off and get into your dough is it? Cutting boards are usually unfinished, or coated with edible oil.

Comment: I assume you're asking about doing the kneading the bread there, right?

Comment: Definitely doing the kneading yes! I do not have a stainless steel flat surface. It's. Cheap wooden table, something you may get at target. I'm not sure what the table is treated with; I hadn't even thought about that honestly. I was more concerned with ruining my table. Now that you mention this, I'm considering what chemicals come can come from my wooden table. Now I'm thinking doing this would not be safe.

Comment: In a pinch, baking paper might make a usable work surface...

Comment: I knead directly in the bowl itself. Granted, I have a large bowl, but it works fine. Also, I use a modified kneading method: Knead ten strokes, let sit ten minutes, repeat for a total of four kneading sessions. Works just fine and just as well as kneading for five or ten minutes straight. Also, I don't use flour, but rather I oil my hands so I introduce no additional flour into the dough to dry the dough out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to use a cutting board for making bread, in fact I would recommend against it. Cutting boards are not big enough for good kneading and they slide around. You are better off using a large flat surface which won't move around. As for what that surface is it doesn't matter much as long as it is clean and doesn't have materials which may come off on your dough. As an example many people use spray polish or furniture wax on their tables which would make the surface unsuitable for bread. You don't want to eat polish or wax!

Comment: That's what "pastry boards" like the IKEA Lämplig are made for ... huge, and they can be solidly clamped between your body and the counter.

Comment: The ones with a lip that hooks over the edge of the counter would be fine. Still, the big ones are hard to clean at the sink and you end up cleaning them in place most of the time anyway.